# putExtra How send to new Activity Arraylist <STRING []>

Tags: java, android, arraylist

How send send Arraylist to another activity??

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String[]> s) {
    Intent newActivity =  new Intent(main,ListadoUltimosRegistros.class);
    newActivity.putExtra("LR",(ArrayList<String[]>)s);
    newActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    main.startActivity(newActivity);
}
```

Comment: The comments are right, the easiest solution is to send it through as a `Serializable`.

Comment: Thanks for their help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
you can use data serializable class and use in put extra statements
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DataList.class);
            i.putExtra("password", (Serializable) contactList);
           startActivity(i);
//and fetch the data as a
if(getIntent().getSerializableExtra("password")!=null)
 {
            con=(ArrayList<Contact>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("password");
            email_mobile = contactList.get(0)._emnumber;
            pass__word = contactList.get(0)._password;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can send your custom object as :

```
intent.putExtra("MyClass", obj);

// To retrieve object in second Activity
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClass");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this.**

**On your onPostExecute for Sending.**

```
Intent newActivity =  new Intent(main,ListadoUltimosRegistros.class);
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
newActivity.putExtra("mylist", myList);
newActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
newActivity.startActivity(newActivity);
```

**on Receiving end use this.**

```
ArrayList<String> myList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("mylist");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

For sending:

```
i.putStringArrayListExtra("list", your list);
```

For retrieving:

```
 getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra(list)
```

Where `i` is the Intent object.

Comment: It's a `List<String[]>`, not `List<String>`

Comment: for passBundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putSerializable("2D array",  arrayToSend);
i.putExtras(mBundle);   and for fetching String[][] arrayReceived=null;
Object[] objectArray = (Object[]) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("2 D array");

Comment: passBundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putSerializable("2D array", arrayToSend);
Object[] objectArray = (Object[]) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("2 D array");